# listview with dynamic data from xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp

I am working on android chat application. I am facing a problem in send and receive function using xmpp. I am able to send message from emulator to xmpp and receive message from xmpp. But i am facing issue in displaying the incoming and outgoing message in a list view. I am confused how to give the condition to set view layout.

```
if(message from xmpp) {
    TextView textLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textb); // if message received dislay in left side textview
    textLabel.setText(receiveddata); //receiveddata contains arraylist of incoming message
} else (message from me) {
    TextView textLabel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.texts); // if message sent by me dislay in right side textview
    textLabel.setText(sentdata); //sentdata contains arraylist of outgoing message
}
```

Kindly tell me how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an adapter class having two layout having same field. use if condition for incoming and outgoing messages. and inflate accordingly.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        entry = list.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
                convertView = inflator.inflate(
                        R.layout.messages_even_list_layout, null);
            } else {
                convertView = inflator.inflate(
                        R.layout.messages_odd_list_layout, null);
            }
```

Comment: getItemViewType check it in android docs.An integer representing the type of View. Two views should share the same type if one can be converted to the other in getView. Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount - 1. IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE can also be returned.